# Wso2 user self registration to a tenantDomain returns 401 Unauthorized

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am trying to register a new user into a tenant, I created tenant `'abc.com'` by referring to [this document](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/Creating+and+Managing+Tenants).

From the [self registration document](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS590/apidocs/self-registration/#!/operations#SelfRegister#mePost) found that base url looks like

```
https://apis.is.com/t/{tenant-domain}/api/identity/user/v1.0/me
```

based on this

```
https://apis.is.com/t/abc/api/identity/user/v1.0/me
```

From [this document](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS590/apidocs/self-registration/#!/models#SelfRegistrationUser), I added one parameter to request body `"tenantDomain":"abc"`.

Final request body

```
{"user": {"username": "abcdc","realm": "PRIMARY", "password": "Password12!","tenantDomain":"abc","claims": [{"uri": "http://wso2.org/claims/givenname","value": "kim" },{"uri": "http://wso2.org/claims/emailaddress","value": "abcdxyz@test.com"},{"uri": "http://wso2.org/claims/lastname","value": "Anderson"},{"uri": "http://wso2.org/claims/mobile","value": "+947721584558"} ] },"properties": []}
```

This is throwing "401 Unauthorized".

Answer (score 0):

Have you set this header?

```
Authorization: Basic <Base64Encoded_admin_username:admin_password>
```

Comment: yes,I have set header,same is working when i register a carbon user ie (https://apis.is.com/api/identity/user/v1.0/me  without tenantDomain)